# How to format file system paths in website code I need to port to electron

Tags: electron

I need to convert a website into a local electron application. Part of the website loads an Excel file from the 'assets' folder. Here is the code that loads the xlsx file:

`SimpleXL.load("/assets/data/List.xlsx", printJSON)`

Initially I had a lot of trouble utilizing fonts and other files from the website. I did some digging and found this code resolved most problems:

```
 function createWindow() {
 const WEB_FOLDER = 'web';
 const PROTOCOL = 'file';

 electron.protocol.interceptFileProtocol(PROTOCOL, (request, callback) => {
  let url = request.url.substr(PROTOCOL.length + 1);

  url = path.join(__dirname, WEB_FOLDER, url);

  url = path.normalize(url);

  console.log(url);
  callback({path: url});
});

mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
width: 800,
height: 600,
webPreferences: {
  nodeIntegration: false
}
});

mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
pathname: 'index.html',
protocol: PROTOCOL + ':',
slashes: true
}));`
```

All other files seem to work, only, When loading the xlsx file the 'interceptFileProtocol' method does intercept the call and changes the url to:
C:\electron\list\dist\assets\data\List.xlsx
Which is correct, however, in the electron app the error is:
main.bundle.js?92b99b2442c75f3217f1:8 GET file:///assets/data/List.xlsx net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

It appears the application is using the '/assets/data/List.xlsx' path that is hardcoded in the website javascript.

When I changed the call to: 
`SimpleXL.load("assets/data/List.xlsx", printJSON)`

The xlsx file did not load.

The xlsx file did load when I modified the loadURL call to be:
`mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname:path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'),
        protocol:'file',
    slashes: true
    }));`

Only, making this change resulted in the fonts no longer being loaded.

I expect the XLSX file and the fonts to load into the website code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is to utilize this method to open the fileURL because it opens the xlsx file successfully:

```
 mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
 pathname:path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'),
     protocol:'file',
 slashes: true
 }));
```

And change every instance of "/assets" to "assets". This made the css paths (and everything else) work just fine.